# How can I make a ViewController conform to multiple protocols?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, protocols

I want to include Core Location and I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/ and I am using SDK 3.2.2.

`@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate>{` is the code right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a class to conform to multiple protocols you just separate the protocol names in the `<>`s with commas:

```
@interface MyClass : TheSuperclass <Protocol1, Protocol2, Protocol3>
    ...
@end
```

and so forth.

In your case:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
    ...
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

`@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>{`